# Errors when assambling an *.asm program

Tags: assembly

I have to get a presentation for college for the next days so I need to learn a program in Assambler language how it works line by line.I have took this source code from web and I realised that he doesn't have a header like: .model stack and data so I have putted them.However I have 4 more errors to fix.
The program should do this:
;Gives you an on-screen button to click on with the mouse, and
;proceeds only when you do!

Here is the source code of the program:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
;Gives you an on-screen button to click on with the mouse, and
;proceeds only when you do!
mov ah,06h ;this calls SCROLL SCREEN UP
mov al,00h ;AL specifies how many lines... 0 just clears the screen
mov ch,00h
mov cl,00h
mov dh,24h
mov dl,80h
int 10h

;The above lines just clear the screen.

mov ah,02h ;Set cursor position
mov dh,0Bh ;row
mov dl,22h ;column
int 10h    ;Actually does it. :)
MOV AX,SEG MESSAGE
MOV DS,AX               
MOV DX,OFFSET MESSAGE

mov ah,0009             ;9 in AH makes INT 21 print the string
int 21h                 ;referenced in DS:DX.

;So, we have printed BUTTON right where we want it!!!

mov ax,0001
int 33h

;Now, that's got the mouse on.

MOUSLOOP:

MOV AX,5     ;5 in AX tells INT 33 to get mouse button press info
INT 33h      ;get mouse button info
CMP AX,1b    ;this compares AX (button status) with 1
JNE MOUSLOOP ;unless LEFT button ONLY is pressed, go back to MOUSLOOP

;(Only the left button will work for this... Not the right.)

MOV AX,3
INT 33h      ;Now we're getting the POSITION info through INT 33,3!

;CX now is mouse horizontal position. 0 - 639
;DX now is mouse vertical position. 0 - 199

CMP CX,270
JL MOUSLOOP ;If CX is less than 270 (left edge of button), go back
CMP CX,315
JG MOUSLOOP ;If CX if more than 400 (right edge), go back
CMP DX,85
JL MOUSLOOP ;If DX is less than 85 (top), go back
CMP DX,95
JG MOUSLOOP ;If DX is more than 110 (bottom), go back

;The numbers above for the button dimensions are approximations, but
;should be good enough.

mov ax,0002
int 33h

;This just hides the cursor. Otherwise it would stay on when the program
;ended! :)

mov ah,4ch             ;terminate program
int 21h

MESSAGE: DB 'BUTTON$'
```

errors are next:

```
Line 34 - CS unreachable from current segment
Line 70 - CS unreachable from current segment
FATAL line 71 - Unexpected end of file encountered
```

I am using windows 8.1 on 64x and DoxBox to tasm the programs.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi there, Really sorry, but stack exchange isn't really there to do your homework for you. I recommend putting in a couple of all nighters.

Comment: I don't see any `.code` directive in your source.

Comment: Yes Miachel I have forgot about .code.The only problem I have now is this error:FATAL line 71 - Unexpected end of file encountered

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding end to the end of file, thank you Miachel for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough points to comment so I'm putting this as an answer:

Is this TASM? You haven't stated your assembler.

```
.data
.code
MAIN PROC
MAIN ENDP
END
```

or

```
main:
end main
end
```

Whatever it is you're doing for code in your particular assembler.

That should explain the end of file issues and the issues with your implementation of each segment. I'm a bit new, but I think you're just not ending the blocks of code.

Also, your code is in 16bit, which could cause issues if you're running windows.

Comment: If `end main` appears in your source, it tells the assembler to stop reading lines.  (And sets the entry point address to `main`.)  That applies regardless of whether you use proc/endp or just `main:` to define main.